# Keybinding notations for GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

Running `GNU screen` on `Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS` remotely from a windows machine. I am trying to change the keybinding in `~/.screenrc`. To navigate between the windows,

```
# control-left and control-right switch windows
bindkey "^[[5D" prev
bindkey "^[[5C" next
```

`[[5D` and `[[5C`  do not translate to `->` and `<-` keys. Manpage of `GNU screen`advices to use caret for `ctrl` key. However, it does not say anything about other keys such as `tab`, `shift` etc.

How do I represent such keystrokes?

What exactly are these symbols(`[5D` and `[5C`) ? Where do I get the list for all such symbols?

Note - The terminal emulator I am using is `GNU Screen`

Edit - so, the symbols are `ASCII` Escape Sequences. [LINK](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

Answer (score 0):

The **`^[`** in your example represents a single character: ASCII escape (code 27).  The various sequences depend on the terminal you are using, as well as whether it is using normal- or application-mode.

GNU screen doesn't determine those sequences; it allows (most) conventional function-keys to pass through.  Whatever the actual terminal you are using *from Windows* would be the place to look for documentation.

In normal mode, cursor-keys for VT100-like terminals (including xterm) send <kbd>Escape</kbd>, followed by <kbd>`[`</kbd>, optionally followed by one or more numeric parameters and terminated by one of <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>.  The first two characters change in *application mode* to <kbd>Escape</kbd> followed by the letter <kbd>O</kbd>.  Each of these features has names, e.g., as listed in [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (CSI, SS3, *final* byte).

Normally the first (optional) parameter would be a *repeat count*.  An early version of xterm's modifier keys would instead send a parameter corresponding to the type of modifier (5 being *control*).  For quite a while, that modifier information has been in the second parameter, e.g.,

```
^[[1;5A
```

for *control up-arrow*.  Modifiers like this (and in fact as used for *function keys* — not VT100 anyway) are not VT100 features but adapted in xterm from a description of the VT510 or a similar model.

Further reading:

- *[Why can't I use the cursor keys in (whatever) shell?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows)* (xterm FAQ)
- *[My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode)* (ncurses FAQ)

Comment: I am using `XShell` with type `Xterm` terminal, on windows.
But, I tried using `xterm` sequences too.
How does the mode factor effect?

Comment: If XShell has documentation, that's the place to go.  I've seen nothing except advertisements for XShell, no documentation.